# More switching between users in scripts

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I want write script for checking SAP. I run my script from jump server -

```
ssh <server> "bash -s" < <script>
```

I am logging to server with my personal credentials, so I am able to perform basic checks - cpu utilization, ram utilization etc... But I need run some coomand in my script as adm.
Could you help me please how can I switch in my script to root, from root to adm and under adm run anycommand?

Running script from jump -> connected to server under my personal accounts -> switch to root -> switch to adm -> run commands in script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accomplish running a command as a different user by using the `sudo` command, like

```
sudo /command/to/run/as/root
```

or

```
sudo -u adm /command/to/run/as/adm
```

Note that you will have to configure `NOPASSWD` in your sudoers configuration for the commands you want to run if you want this to run without prompting for a password, and you might have to you remove the `requiretty` options from your sudoers configuration as well.  There are lots of questions on here and serverfault about these last two points.

Comment: Yes, it is working but we have internal rules that we have to connect on server with our personal credentials, next switch on root and from root on adm user.....

Comment: Ok, so like `sudo -u root sudo -u adm /path/to/command`?  If that's not it, you need to clarify in your question what *exactly* you mean by "switch to root".

Comment: But what to do if I want run script from jump server?

Comment: Yeah so you would do like `ssh server sudo bash ...`